# XSS Shell error: Variable "fm_QNSTR" not defined

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

The error while executing the file is:

> VARIABLE fm_QNSTR not defined

Here's the part of the code. fm_QNSTR is on the 2nd line only.

```vbs
'// Password protected pages
Sub protected()

'XSS Shell Proxy Check 
If fm_Qnstr("XSSSHELLPROXY") > 0 Then
    Response.Write 13
    Response.End
End If

Dim ThisPage
ThisPage = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))

Dim Pass
Pass = Request.Form("pass")
If Len(Pass) = 0 Then Pass = Request.Querystring("pass")

'// Set Session + password is Case Sensitive
If Pass <> "" Then
    If Trim(Pass) = "w00t" Then Session("level") = "ok"
    'Response.Redirect ""
End If

'// Logout (xxx.asp?logout=ok)
If Request.Querystring("logout") <> "" Then Session("level") = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

`fm_Qnstr` is not a vbscript or intrinsic function. You must define it. Googling it, it appears that it needs to be

```
Function fm_QNStr(byVal Qstring)
    Qstring= Trim(Request.Querystring(Qstring))
    If NOT IsNumeric(Qstring) Then fm_QNStr = 0 Else fm_QNStr = Qstring
End Function
```